# Strange return range result in Google Sheets / App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have simple sheet with data and code:

[image]

```
function test() {
var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
var frozenRows = Sheet.getFrozenRows(); 2.0
var lastRow = Sheet.getLastRow(); // 3.0
var lastColumn = Sheet.getLastColumn(); // 3.0
var headerRange = Sheet.getRange(1, 1, frozenRows, 1); // A1:A2
var dataRange = Sheet.getRange(1 + frozenRows, 1, lastRow, lastColumn); // A3:C5
var Range = Sheet.getDataRange(); // A1:C3
```

I don't understand why I get return value **A3:C5** and not **A3:C3** from:

```
var dataRange = Sheet.getRange(1 + frozenRows, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);

Logger.log(dataRange.getA1Notation());
```

Thank you.

Comment: Result of `Logger.log(Sheet.getLastColumn())`?

Comment: check if you accidentally put a value somewhere in your sheet (in the next columns) and therefore the script considers that as the last column.

Comment: @ TheMaster  I forgot mention, it is `Logger.log(dataRange.getA1Notation());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) method has the syntax `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`

Thus, `getRange(3, 1, 3, 3)` will result in a range that

- starts in column 1 row 3 (`A3`)
- ist 3 columns wide
- and 3 rows long
- So: `A3:C:5`
- To retrieve the range `A3:C3` instead you need to query:
  `getRange(3, 1, 1, 3)`
- In other words:

```js
var startRow = (1 + frozenRows);
var rowLength = (lastRow - startRow + 1);
var startColumn = 1;
var columnLength = (lastColumn - startColumn + 1);
var dataRange = Sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, rowLength, columnLength);
```